# SBT download error for ivy.xml although it exists

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-plugin

SBT:
[error]   download error: `Caught java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (Connection reset) while downloading`
for example on `**sbt-plugin**`

```
https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugi
n/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.2/ivys/ivy.xml
```

But ivy.xml exists.

It happens for example on play-samples-2.8.x, with Scala 2.13.1, Play 2.8.2, SBT 1.3.8

Tkank you in advance, Marcin

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this not a Scala, sbt or play framework related problem, but probably what the Java runtime reports. A glitch in the connection, somehow a change in your ip-address etc. Certainly Java runtime environment, connection or hardware.
Proszę dziękuję.

Comment: Works for some others artifacts.  I am connected by proxy with `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` as JAVA_FLAGS. but . Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. More correctly: works for some artifacts, doesn't work for others (more often for some plugins). I can't predict the logic.